# How should I get a large list of options that are saved to chrome.storage in my Chrome extensions' content script?

Tags: asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, message-passing, google-chrome-storage

I have an options page in my Chrome extension with a very large list of values that get saved to `chrome.storage`. These options get used across several different websites. In order to use the options I have to retrieve them in my content scripts that load on these websites.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this. I'm fairly confident that once I get my options loaded during a session on a website that I would want to save them to `sessionstorage` or `localStorage` so that I can have quick synchronous access to them on subsequent page loads of that same site.

But the initial retrieval of those options is where I'm wondering what's the best method. My gut says to just make all of the asynchronous calls for each individual option from my content script at `document_start` and return a promise once I've retrieved them all using `Promise.all()`.

My other idea was using message passing to talk to the background page where all of my options can already be available because I will have done the async calls when Chrome started or because I could just skip chrome.storage and store them in the background pages' `localStorage`. In this case, each different website that needs the options is just sending one message to the background page instead of making 40+ async calls to `chrome.storage`.

Comment: Ideally background page should be non-persistent so it's be better to reorganize chrome.storage to store the site values individually per site instead of a huge common array/object.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you clarify that? The options I'll be saving in storage will be used across all matching sites. There won't be any options that are just for one site or another. Right now I've got 40+ options stored individually as 40+ key/value pairs.

Comment: Well, start with measuring the time spent to read the storage. Maybe there's nothing to worry about. Also note, messaging has overhead as well due to the internal JSONification.